# ASP.NET MVC 5 bundled scripts not being called in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, scriptbundle

Before I start let me say that I know there are other questions on SO about this issues that have great answers but please let me explain how mine is different.

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project where I have a collection of bundles:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));


        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/freelancer.css"));

        // Plugin JavaScript
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/pluginjs").Include(
                "~/Scripts/cbpAnimatedHeader.js",
                "~/Scripts/classie.js"));

        //Custom Theme js
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/customthemejs").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/freelancer.js"));

        // Contact Form JavaScript
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/contactvalidation").Include(
                  "~/Content/jqBootstrapValidation.js",
                  "~/Content/contact_me.js"));
    }
```

These are called in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/customthemejs")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/contactvalidation")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/pluginjs")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)   
</body>
</html>
```

And in `global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

Here is what I know so far:

1. All the `StyleBundle`'s are called and invoked successfully so I can pin point the problem to something within the script referencing
2. The scripts referred too are in the correct folder i.e ~/Scripts/.... so I know that it isn't a referencing issue.
3. The scripts are working as I have tested them using a Web Forms project
4. I have tried referencing the bundles in the `head` section of `_Layout.cshtml` but no change
5. Dev tools in chrome and debugger in VS show the the script is not being run
6. My only suspicion is that there is a gap somewhere between the call from `_Layout.cshtml` and the bundles in `BundleConfig` class

I have tried other solutions that others have recommended around the web such as looking for syntax errors etc... but as far as I am aware there are none.

To make the structure of the scripts obvious I have included a screen shot:
[image]

Can anyone see this in a different perspective than myself and see where I have gone wrong?

Comment: what script is not running? maybe, it's script order issue?

Comment: Did you call RegisterBundles in global.aspx?

Comment: Bundles are called in global.asax. StyleBundles are called just not the script bundles

Comment: When you say scripts bundles are not being called, you mean the scripts are not rendered in browser at all?

Comment: Yeah, the scripts are not being rendered at all

Comment: What error code is the browser showing in the dev console? Also, you have a spelling error in one of your bundles: `~/Content/cantact_me.js`.

Comment: yeah fixed the spelling error, there is no eror in dev console or debugger because the script is not being called so no error could be produced

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks correct, though you're referencing the `Microsoft.Web.Optimization` the application `config` may not be working correctly.  You can force the reference so that the application will utilize the `Web.Optimization`.  Inside of your `_Layout.cshtml` above your bundled data, place the following:

```
@using System.Web.Optimization
```

That should correctly enforce the `Web.Optimization`.

The only other part that may be wrong, we can't see is your Global.asax.  You need to ensure that you call the `RegisterBundle`.

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

Comment: I am already ref s.w.o and BundleConfig.RegisterBundle(BundleTable.Bundles); is called in global.asax

Comment: Yeah, but the shared layout doesn't always, it can bug out in ASP.net.  Is there a squiggle on layout for scripts.render?